# Protected Cells Preventing Macros Functioning

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner. Learnt a bit of VBA only for improving an XLs file. I'm nearly finished, but realize that protecting cells seems to be a problem for my macros to operate. So I have inserted an unprotect/protect function, but still not working (I'm not comfortable with where to place it). I copy/paste hereunder. Many thanks for your help:-)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

MsgBox "Bonjour, Vous êtes bien sur le formulaire RISTOURNES à facturer ou à rembourser"

Call Effacercontenu

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)


Dim myRange As Range

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="350+"


Set myRange = Union(Range("C8"), Range("C10:C11"), Range("C13:C17"), Range("D16:D17"), Range("B22:D22"), Range("B30"), Range("B35"))
For Each cell In myRange
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) = True Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox ("Vérifiez les cellules non remplies")
    End If
Next cell
ActiveSheet.Protect "350+"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Private Sub Effacercontenu()

Dim myRange As Range

With ActiveSheet.Range("C8,C10:C11,C13:C17,D16:D17,B22:D22,B30,B35").ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can protect the sheet from user changes, without blocking the system from changing the cells by using the `UserInterfaceOnly` argument of `WorkSheet.Protect`.

`WorkSheet.Protect Password:="350+", UserInterfaceOnly:=True`

You set this option when the book opens, and then you can leave the sheet protected and not worry about needing to unprotect it for the macros to run.

@BigBen advises, this line needs to run every time the book opens to properly set the `UserInterfaceOnly` property. To enable this, I suggest placing this code in `ThisWorkbook` code module, in the `Workbook_Open` event.

The code should look like:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname")
        If .ProtectContents Then .Unprotect Password:="350+"
        .Protect Password:="350+", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: many thanks Toddleson. the thing is that I probably misplaced this line. it doesn't work. Could you please tell me where to place it in my code ?

Comment: @SOPHIE I have updated my answer to give an example

Comment: thanks very much !. I will try this tomorrow.  The idea is : the user on opening the file, has the cells blanked for input , he makes his input but should have no possibility to delete protected cells where formulas etc..., then he saves the file as an xls.

Comment: Thanks to all, this morning all my xls files work properly and this had nothing to do with a necessary macro to unprotect and protect. It was just the order of tasks to execute manually. save after correcting some cells, then protect, then save again. so stupid my files were all the same but some did not work. At least I learnt via this experience :-) and keep this website in mind.